# Undo vote to close

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close

Is there a way to undo a vote to close a question because you thought it was a dupe and then realized it wasn't?

Comment: There isn't. I think it should be re-tagged http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request

Comment: @ShmuelBrin You can link directly to tags on meta with [ meta - tag : feature - request ] but without all those spaces, ie [meta-tag:feature-request].

Comment: This has now been implemented: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/915 and its comments and answers for more details. (Documentation hasn't been up properly anywhere yet. If anyone wants to, he can post it as an answer here.) Retagging this as [meta-tag:status-completed]. Thanks for theping, @Daniel.

Answer (score 3):

This has been requested on the main meta site, and declined there.

- [Can we have the ability to rescind a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes)

Jeff's explanation was:

> declining -- you can always cast a reopen vote if the post gets closed.
>
> Also note that all close votes automatically expire after two days.
>
> (and for that matter reopen votes, or any other vote that attempts to reach a threshold -- otherwise, over an absurdly long period of time, say 10 years, everything would reach the threshold eventually through a tiny trickle of accumulated votes)

See here for when and how close votes expire:

- [Why do close votes expire?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97581/168660)